# Prepare a python string for R using rpy2

Tags: python, r, string, rpy2

This question relates to [python variable to R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525027/passing-a-python-variable-to-r-using-rpy2) and perhaps also to this [python objects to rpy2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2447454/converting-python-objects-for-rpy2) but none of the two completely overlaps and the first one is actually unanswered.

My question is actually very simple. I have a string, say:

```
In [21]: strg
Out[21]: 'I want to go home'
```

and I want to pass it to R through `robjects.r(''' ''')` like this, for example:

```
robjects.r('''

test <- gsub("to", "",strg)

''')
```

but of course, when I run this I obtain: `Error in gsub("me", "", strg) : object 'strg' not found`.

I have not used `rpy2` much (as obvious) but I guess is related to the environments in which R and Python see the objects.

I have tried a few things, like transforming the string `strg` to an `robject` first and then feed it to `robjects.r(''' ''')` but I get the same error message. Overall, I do not know how do this so that `strg` is seen at the `R` environment.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks in advance for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `strg` value to the command string:

```
robjects.r('''

test <- gsub("to", "",''' + strg + ''')

''')
```

or, by using `.format`:

```
robjects.r('''

test <- gsub("to", "",%s)

'''.format(strg))
```

Do note that you'll need to watch out for backslashes, see the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738648/rpy2-error-unrecognized-escape-in-character-string/30738846#30738846)

Comment: Hi there hajtos. the two of them throw a parsing error: ```ValueError: Error while parsing the string.``` The first at the last line ```----> 5 ''')``` coming from ```--> 310         p = rinterface.parse(string)``` and the second also at the last line: ```----> 5 '''.format(strg))``` coming again from the same function ```--> 310         p = rinterface.parse(string)``` at ```def __call__(self, string):```

Comment: Hi hajtos, I found the reason of the error, which is the ***quotes needed for the R expression to work***. so I simply have to define ```strg = '"I want to go home"'``` and it worked. THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to create an function, as the R function exposed by rpy2 can be called just as if it was a Python function.

```
my_func = robjects.r('''
function(strg) {
    test <- gsub("to", "",strg)
    test
}
''')

my_func(strg)
```