# Is there any way I can pass a python variable to R code?

Tags: python, r, rpy2, reticulate

I have a string variable in my python code: `apple = jo34`

and would like to call an R function to perform the next step.  However, my variable from python needs to be called.  How can I do that?

There have been similar questions asked in the past but none seem to have answered this question directly.

This is not a duplicate of this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754885/prepare-a-python-string-for-r-using-rpy2)
Because that link focuses on gsub

Comment: @Chris_Rands You have any suggestions? I've tried 
robjects.r("{}".format()apple)

Comment: It would be helpful to know what jo34 is an integer, a string, a list?

Comment: @Ben373 Oh yes, it's a string

Comment: What do you want to do with the value once it's in R? The second answer (not the accepted one) would seem to let you pass any value into an R function. Is that not good enough? It would be easier to help with some sort of simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick I want to perform a poisson regression on the csv data in r. Thus that is the reason I wanted to read the csv files. That is the only reason I wanted to use r in the first place